# sorting files using string

Tags: string, file-copy, for

I have a directory of 1000+ files (follow the same formatting) example file would be

```
giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-202007020832-10.std
```

Where year is 2020

month is 07

day is 02

hour is 08

min is 32

elevation is 10

I'd like to create a script that reads the day and hour and sorts it in a folder with that same name then into a sub directory based on elevation. example file would be copied into folder

```
../0208/10.std/
```

I was able to use string features to read the day and hour and create the corresponding folders and also able to create the directories (see below). My issue is that I can't seem to copy the files while using "string reading".

This is where the files are located (may help explain my script attempt and why I used the cut function the way I did.

```
#/home/lmdjeu/qdoas-test/ob10roof/fitting/stdfiles/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-202007020832-10.std
```

```
#!/bin/bash

#/home/lmdjeu/qdoas-test/ob10roof/fitting/stdfiles/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-202007020832-10.std


list=$(ls /home/lmdjeu/qdoas-test/ob10roof/fitting/stdfiles/*.std)
#echo "$list"

dir="$(cut -d'/' -f8 <<<"$list")"

loca="$(cut -d'-' -f5 <<<"$dir")"

elevstd="$(cut -d'-' -f6 <<<"$dir")"


hello="$(cut -c 7-10 <<< "$loca")"

mkdir /home/lmdjeu/test/hello/$hello


elev="$(cut -c 1-2 <<< "$elevstd")"
#echo "$elev"

for dir in /home/lmdjeu/test/hello/*/;
   do
      mkdir -- "$dir"/{00.std,01.std,02.std,03.std,04.std,05.std,06.std,07.std,08.std,09.std,10.std,ref};
   done


stddir=/home/lmdjeu/qdoas-test/ob10roof/fitting/stdfiles
elevdir=/home/lmdjeu/test/hello
```

This is the area of my script that I would like to improve. I want it to copy files into the corresponding directory and subdirectory even if the days and hours change.

```
for i in {00..10}; do
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070111*-"$i".std $elevdir/0111/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070112*-"$i".std $elevdir/0112/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070113*-"$i".std $elevdir/0113/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070114*-"$i".std $elevdir/0114/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070115*-"$i".std $elevdir/0115/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070116*-"$i".std $elevdir/0116/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070117*-"$i".std $elevdir/0117/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070118*-"$i".std $elevdir/0118/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070119*-"$i".std $elevdir/0119/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070120*-"$i".std $elevdir/0120/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070121*-"$i".std $elevdir/0121/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070122*-"$i".std $elevdir/0122/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070123*-"$i".std $elevdir/0123/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070200*-"$i".std $elevdir/0200/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070201*-"$i".std $elevdir/0201/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070202*-"$i".std $elevdir/0202/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070203*-"$i".std $elevdir/0203/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070204*-"$i".std $elevdir/0204/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070205*-"$i".std $elevdir/0205/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070206*-"$i".std $elevdir/0206/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070207*-"$i".std $elevdir/0207/"$i".std
  cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070208*-"$i".std $elevdir/0208/"$i".std
done




cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070111*.ref  $elevdir/0111/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070112*.ref  $elevdir/0112/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070113*.ref  $elevdir/0113/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070114*.ref  $elevdir/0114/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070115*.ref  $elevdir/0115/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070116*.ref  $elevdir/0116/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070117*.ref  $elevdir/0117/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070118*.ref  $elevdir/0118/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070119*.ref  $elevdir/0119/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070120*.ref  $elevdir/0120/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070121*.ref  $elevdir/0121/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070122*.ref  $elevdir/0122/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070123*.ref  $elevdir/0123/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070200*.ref  $elevdir/0200/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070201*.ref  $elevdir/0201/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070202*.ref  $elevdir/0202/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070203*.ref  $elevdir/0203/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070204*.ref  $elevdir/0204/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070205*.ref  $elevdir/0205/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070206*.ref  $elevdir/0206/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070207*.ref  $elevdir/0207/ref/
cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-2020070208*.ref  $elevdir/0208/ref/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

First define where the new directories will be:

```
newdir='/home/lmdjeu/test/hello'
```

Now `cd` to the directory all the files are in:

```
cd /home/lmdjeu/qdoas-test/ob10roof/fitting/stdfiles
```

Now begin a `for` loop to iterate through the `*.std` files in this directory (subsequent actions will be done inside this for loop).

```
for i in *.std; do
```

We need day and hour values from the date string part of the file name and we need the digits before the `.`. Since the date string is always 12 digits, it can be easily defined:

```
    datestring=$(echo "$i" | grep -Eo '[0-9]{12}')
```

Define the day/hour value:

```
    dayhr=$(echo $datestring | cut -c7-10)
```

Define the elevation value:

```
    elev=$(echo "$i" | grep -o '[0-9]\+.std')
```

Now piece together the variables that define the directory this file will be moved to:

```
    loc="$newdir"'/'"$dayhr"'/'"$elev"
```

And finally create the directory and move the file there then close the `for` loop:

```
    mkdir -p "$loc" && mv "$i" "$loc"
done
```

This way the directory/subdirectory each file will be moved to will always be derived from that file's name, the directory will be created if necessary, then the file moved into it. Putting it all together in one script:

```bsh
newdir='/home/lmdjeu/test/hello'
cd /home/lmdjeu/qdoas-test/ob10roof/fitting/stdfiles || exit 1
for i in *.std; do
    datestring=$(echo "$i" | grep -Eo '[0-9]{12}')
    dayhr=$(echo $datestring | cut -c7-10)
    elev=$(echo "$i" | grep -o '[0-9]\+.std')
    loc="$newdir"'/'"$dayhr"'/'"$elev"
    mkdir -p "$loc" && mv "$i" "$loc"
done
```

This could be done with fewer steps and variables, but I think the above helps illustrate one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your request to its full depth, but you might want to try how far this would get you (assuming `bash` shell as in your recent posts):

```
for i in {00..10}
  do    for j in {01..02}{00..23}
          do    echo cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-202007"$j"*-"$i".std $elevdir/"$j"/"$i".std
          done
        echo cp $stddir/giroof-doas-ob10roof-L1-202007"$j"*.ref $elevdir/"$j"/ref/
  done
```

In the `j` loop, adjust day/hour to taste. For simplicity, it will try to `cp` all computed files and fail on non-existant ones; you could suppress stderr if need be. Or refine the construction of file names to the relevant ones.

For your upfront directory creation, you might try something along this line:

```
cd /home/lmdjeu/qdoas-test/ob10roof/fitting/stdfiles/
for FN in *
  do    IFS=".-" read X X X X loca elev std X <<< "$FN"
#       hello="${loca:6:4}"
#       elevstd="$elev$std"
        echo mkdir -p -- "/home/lmdjeu/test/hello/${loca:6:4}/"{{00..10}.std,ref}
   done
```

In either case, remove the `echo` if happy with what you see.